# Clicking the Google OAuth2 Approve button with phantomjs/selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, google-oauth

I am trying to automate the sign in/approve oauth2 sequence in google using headless phantomjs or selenium (htmlunitwithjs driver).
I successfully sign in, but when i try to click the Approve button, nothing happens.

Also, when running selenium script with chrome driver (with browser window opened), everything works fine, so I suspect there is nothing wrong with my scripts.

My question is: is there some bot protection enabled on the Approve page the prevents the headless browsers from clicking the Approve button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing phantomjs' user agent and see if that makes a difference:

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Apparently the 'Accept' and 'Cancel' buttons on the Google OAuth2 page are disabled for 500ms after the page load.

Simply making the page wait after loading for 1 second solved the issue for me.

There is no bot protection enabled on the page.